# Python: Вычислить формулу из строки

Tags: python, парсер

Есть строка, к примеру `x+1j*y`.
Я хочу присвоить переменной значение просчитанной строки с переменными x, y.
Т.е `v=magic("x+1j*y")(x=x,y=y)`.

`exec` не использую в целях безопасности. Все парсеры, которые нашёл, либо не умеют работать с комплексными числами, либо криво это делают (например https://github.com/glenfletcher/Equation)

Какие есть безопасные парсеры для этого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если синтаксис выражений совпадает с синтаксисом python, то можно воспользоваться его собственным парсером, но куда более безопасным способом, чем с помощью `eval`/`exec`

`ast.parse` генерирует абстрактное синтаксическое дерево, не выполняя никакого кода, соответственно ничего страшнее переполнения стека (**вплоть до падения интерпретатора, имейте в виду**) случиться не должно. Дерево получается такого вида:

```
BinOp(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
      op=Add(),
      right=BinOp(left=Num(n=1j),
                  op=Mult(),
                  right=Name(id='y', ctx=Load())))
```

Дальше его очень просто распарсить и посчитать результат (тут тоже не исключено переполнение стека из за рекурсии, но уже отлавливаемое):

```py
import ast
import operator

binops = {
    ast.Add: operator.add,
    ast.Mult: operator.mul,
}

unops = {
    ast.USub: operator.neg,
}

def magic(text):
    def wrapped(**names):
        def _eval(expr):
            if isinstance(expr, ast.BinOp):
                return binops[type(expr.op)](_eval(expr.left), _eval(expr.right))
            elif isinstance(expr, ast.UnaryOp):
                return unops[type(expr.op)](_eval(expr.operand))
            elif isinstance(expr, ast.Num):
                return expr.n
            elif isinstance(expr, ast.Name):
                return names[expr.id]
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'unknown action {ast.dump(expr)}')

        return _eval(expr)

    expr = ast.parse(text, mode='eval').body
    return wrapped

print(magic('x+1j*y')(x=5, y=10)) # (5+10j)
```

Точно таким же образом действует библиотечная функция
[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), но она очень ограничена по функционалу – с переменными работать не умеет, а в этот код и поддержку вызова функций можно прикрутить (`ast.Call`).